# Changing JavaScript into jQuery - createElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, dom

I'm trying to use the draggable and resizable jQuery function, but I may have to change a little bit of this code to jQuery.

I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="resizable2" class="ui-widget-content">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">MS</h3>
</div>
```

This works great with the jQuery:

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#resizable" ).draggable();
    $( "#resizable" ).resizable();
}
```

But then, I've tried to use it with a div created by javascript:

```
function addnewbox() {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
    var h = document.createElement("h3"); 
    var text = document.createTextNode("MS"); 
    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
    newDiv.appendChild(h);  
    newDiv.className = "ui-widget-content";
    h.appendChild(text);   
    h.className = "ui-widget-header";
    newDiv.id = "resizable";
}
```

And it's not working

Comment: Not working how? Could you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can see the problem?

Comment: The `draggable()` and `resizable()` are called on the current elements. When you create a new element you must manually make them draggable and resizable too. Besides that, you can't create elements that have the same id's of existing ones (you can, but you shouldn't)

Comment: Javascript executes in a linear fashion meaning the order in which you have declared your functions affects when they are called. To make the new div resizeable you have to call the `draggable()` and `resizeable()` methods on it after it has been created - like in the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your dom object to a jQuery object by calling `$(newdiv)` and re-initialise the `resizable` and `draggable` functionality on the new content.

```
function addnewbox() {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
    var h = document.createElement("h3"); 
    var text = document.createTextNode("MS"); 
    newDiv.appendChild(h);  
    newDiv.className = "ui-widget-content";
    h.appendChild(text);   
    h.className = "ui-widget-header";
    newDiv.id = "resizable";
    $(newDiv).resizable(); //Add this
    $(newDiv).draggable(); //and this

    document.body.appendChild(newDiv); //Append to the dom once you've finished with it.
}
```

As devqon has mentioned, the reason for this is that this function adds dynamic content (content which isn't there on page load) this means that the draggable and resizable functionality is not present on this new content. This is why you need to re-initialise the connection between the new element and the functionality.

Also as menioned don't re-use ID's, they must be unique. It is bad practice to use the same id for multiple elements and will very likely lead to other issues.

Lastly, it is a good idea when creating new content to manipulate it first and add it to the page at the end. In this instance you are appending further content inside the newly created `div`. I would do this first and then when finished with it, add it to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have changed your function to:

```
function addnewbox() {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
    var h = document.createElement("h3"); 
    var text = document.createTextNode("MS"); 
    newDiv.id = "resizable";
    newDiv.className = "ui-widget-content";
    h.className = "ui-widget-header";
    h.appendChild(text);   
    newDiv.appendChild(h);  

    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);

}
```

And I have created a jsfiddle for you to try yourself:

http://jsfiddle.net/ttw7218z/4/

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to initialize resiazble plugin on new DOM elements. You already have a few JS solutions so I will post one more version using jQuery for elements creation:

```
function addnewbox() {
    $('<div class="ui-widget-content resizable">' +
          '<h3 class="ui-widget-header">MS</h3>' +
      '</div>').appendTo('body').resizable();
}
```

One more thin you should be aware of: you should not duplicate ids, they must be unique. So instead of multiple `#resizable` use `.resizable` classes.